# Open an XML file through URL and save it

Tags: python, python-3.6

With Python 3, I want to read an XML web page and save it in my local drive.
Also, if the file already exist, it must overwrite it.

I tested some script like :

```
import urllib.request
xml = urllib.request.urlopen('URL')
data = xml.read()
file = open("file.xml","wb")
file.writelines(data)
file.close()
```

But I have an error :

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

Comment: Whenever python gives you a stacktrace, please post the full stacktrace instead of just the error message. This helps _a lot_ locate the exact error, instead of just guessing where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

xml = open("import.xml", "r+")

xml.write(urlopen('URL').read().decode('utf-8'))

xml.close()
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why not `xml = open("import.xml", "w")`

Answer (score 2):

First suggestion: do what even the [official urllib docs says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) and don't use `urllib`, use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) instead.

Your problem is that you use `.writelines()` and it expects a list of lines, not a bytes objects (for once in Python the error message is not very helpful). Use `.write()` instead

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('URL')
with open('file.xml', 'wb') as foutput:
   foutput.write(resp.content)
```